# react-paypal-js not changing currency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider
      options={{
        "client-id": process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        currency: "PHP",
      }}
    >
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
}
```

I specified the currency in the properties of paypal script provider but it's still in usd
[Purchase Image showing USD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQbzL.png)

What should I do to change the currency of it to Philippine Peso

Here is the link of the npm package that i used:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js

Whole Code

```js
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import { PayPalButtons, PayPalScriptProvider } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import {
  arrayUnion,
  collection,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  serverTimestamp,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, storage } from "./firebase.js";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadString } from "firebase/storage";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import thanks from "./Images/thanks.png";

function PaypalCheckoutButton(props) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleApprove = (orderID) => {
    props.completeOrder();
  };

  if (error) {
    alert(error);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <PayPalButtons
        createOrder={(data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: props.product.description,
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "PHP",
                  value: props.product.price,
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        }}
        onApprove={async (data, action) => {
          const order = await action.order.capture();
          console.log("order", order);

          handleApprove(data.orderID);
        }}
        onCancel={() => {}}
        onError={(err) => {
          setError(err);
          console.log("Paypal Checkout Error", err);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Step1(props) {
  const [isGift, setIsGift] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  function newKeychain() {
    setIsGift(null);
    props.setOrders((currentOrders) => [
      { image: props.image, message: message },
      ...currentOrders,
    ]);
    props.setImage(null);
  }

  function handleShowButton() {
    if (isGift === false) {
      return props.image;
    } else if (isGift === true) {
      return props.image && message !== "";
    }
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="step1 step"
      style={isGift === true ? { marginTop: "5rem" } : {}}
    >
      {isGift === null && (
        <>
          <h1 className="title">Choose what type of keychain</h1>
          <div className="purchaseTypeSection">
            <div
              className="formyself purchaseType"
              onClick={() => setIsGift(false)}
            >
              <h2>Standard</h2>
              <p className="keychainTypeDescription">
                Perfect for personal use
              </p>

              <h2 className="price">₱69</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="gift purchaseType" onClick={() => setIsGift(true)}>
              <h2>With Message</h2>
              <p className="keychainTypeDescription">
                Perfect for gifts to your love ones
              </p>
              <h2 className="price">₱99</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
      {isGift !== null && (
        <>
          <h1 className="title">Choose your image</h1>
          <Dropzone
            onDrop={(acceptedFiles) =>
              props.setImage(() => {
                if (!acceptedFiles[0]) {
                  return null;
                }

                var fr = new FileReader();

                fr.onload = function () {
                  props.setImage(fr.result);
                };

                fr.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
              })
            }
            multiple={false}
            accept={{ "image/jpeg": [".png", ".jpg"] }}
          >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
              <section>
                <div
                  {...getRootProps()}
                  style={props.image ? { padding: "0 !important" } : {}}
                >
                  <input {...getInputProps()} />
                  {props.image ? (
                    <img
                      className="drop__image"
                      src={props.image}
                      alt="Your Keychain"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <h3 className="drop__text">
                      Drag your image here, or click to select a file
                    </h3>
                  )}
                </div>
              </section>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
          {isGift === true && (
            <textarea
              className="messageInput largeInput"
              maxLength={100}
              placeholder="Enter your message to your special someone here"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
          )}

          <div className="step1Buttons">
            <button
              className="step1Button"
              onClick={() => {
                setIsGift(null);
                props.setImage(null);
              }}
            >
              Go back
            </button>
            {handleShowButton() && (
              <>
                <button className="step1Button" onClick={newKeychain}>
                  Create Another Keychain
                </button>
                <button
                  className="step1Button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    newKeychain();
                    props.setStep((step) => step + 1);
                  }}
                >
                  Next
                </button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Step2(props) {
  function completed() {
    return (
      props.customerName !== "" &&
      props.customerNumber > 0 &&
      props.customerAddress !== ""
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="step2 step center">
      <div className="question center">
        <h3>Let us know who will we deliver it to</h3>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          value={props.customerName}
          onChange={(e) => props.setCustomerName(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="question center">
        <h3>For us to give you infomations about the delivery and package</h3>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter your phone number"
          value={props.customerNumber}
          onChange={(e) => props.setCustomerNumber(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="question center">
        <h3>Let us know where to deliver</h3>
        <textarea
          className="largeInput locationInput"
          placeholder="Enter your location"
          value={props.customerAddress}
          onChange={(e) => props.setCustomerAddress(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <div className="step1Buttons">
        <button
          className="step1Button createAnother"
          onClick={() => props.setStep((step) => step - 1)}
        >
          Go Back
        </button>
        <button
          className="step1Button"
          style={
            completed()
              ? { backgroundColor: "#5c90a0", cursor: "pointer" }
              : { backgroundColor: "#b5b5b5", cursor: "default" }
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (!completed()) {
              return;
            }
            props.setStep((step) => step + 1);
          }}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Step3(props) {
  function getPrice() {
    var p = 0;

    props.orders.forEach((o) => {
      if (o.message === "") {
        p += 69;
      } else {
        p += 99;
      }
    });

    return p;
  }

  function getDescription() {
    var giftCount = 0;
    var standardCount = 0;

    props.orders.forEach((o) => {
      if (o.message === "") {
        standardCount += 1;
      } else {
        giftCount += 1;
      }
    });

    return `${giftCount > 0 ? `${giftCount} Gift Keychain/s` : ""}${
      giftCount * standardCount !== 0 ? " and " : ""
    }${standardCount > 0 ? `${standardCount} Standard Keychain/s` : ""}`;
  }

  async function completeOrder(method) {
    // get the order informations
    // add it to the orders collection in firebase
    const orderId = uuidv4();
    await setDoc(doc(db, "orders", orderId), {
      customerName: props.customerName,
      customerNumber: props.customerNumber,
      customerAddress: props.customerAddress,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      paymentMethod: method,
      description: getDescription(),
      price: getPrice(),
      status: "toApprove",
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < props.orders.length; i++) {
      let order = props.orders[i];
      const fileRef = ref(storage, `orders/${orderId}`);

      await uploadString(fileRef, order.image, "data_url").then(
        async (snapshot) => {
          const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

          updateDoc(doc(db, "orders", orderId), {
            orders: arrayUnion({
              keychainImage: downloadUrl,
              keychainMessage: order.message,
            }),
          });
        }
      );
    }

    props.setHasOrdered(true);
    props.setOrders([]);
    props.setCustomerName("");
    props.setCustomerAddress("");
    props.setCustomerNumber("");
    props.setStep(1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="step3 step">
      <button
        className="paymentMethod cod"
        onClick={() => completeOrder("Cash On Delivery")}
      >
        Cash on Delivery
      </button>
      <h2 style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>Or</h2>

      <PaypalCheckoutButton
        completeOrder={() => completeOrder("Online")}
        product={{ description: getDescription(), price: getPrice() }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function LandingPage(props) {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  const [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState("");
  const [customerNumber, setCustomerNumber] = useState();
  const [customerAddress, setCustomerAddress] = useState("");

  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);

  const bottomRef = useRef();
  const topRef = useRef();

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const changeBackground = () => {
    setNavbar(window.scrollY > 0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);
  function handleStepIndicator() {
    if (step === 1) {
      return "Step 1. Create your keychains";
    } else if (step === 2) {
      return "Step 2. Delivery Informations";
    } else if (step === 3) {
      return "Step 3. Payment Method";
    }
  }

  const [hasOrdered, setHasOrdered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {hasOrdered && (
        <>
          <div className="overlay" onClick={() => setHasOrdered(false)} />

          <div className="purchaseModal">
            <img src={thanks} alt="thanks" className="thanksImage"></img>
            <h2>Thank you for your purchase</h2>
            <p className="purchaseInfo">
              We will inform you about the package via phone number that you
              gave us
            </p>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
      <div className="top" ref={topRef} style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }} />
      <section className="hero">
        <div
          className={`hero__navbar ${navbar && "active"}`}
          onClick={() => {
            topRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          }}
        >
          <h2
            className="hero__nav"
            onClick={() => {
              topRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
            }}
          >
            KEYCH
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div className="hero__about">
          <h1 className="hero__headline">BRING YOUR KEYCHAIN IDEAS TO LIFE</h1>
          <p className="hero__support">
            We make handmade and customized keychains using images that you like
          </p>
        </div>

        <button
          className="hero__cta"
          onClick={() => {
            bottomRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          }}
        >
          <h3>Create Now</h3>
        </button>
      </section>
      <section className="creation">
        <h1 className="creation__stepIndicator">{handleStepIndicator()}</h1>

        {step === 1 && (
          <Step1
            image={image}
            setImage={setImage}
            orders={orders}
            setOrders={setOrders}
            setStep={setStep}
          />
        )}
        {step === 2 && (
          <Step2
            customerName={customerName}
            setCustomerName={setCustomerName}
            customerNumber={customerNumber}
            setCustomerNumber={setCustomerNumber}
            customerAddress={customerAddress}
            setCustomerAddress={setCustomerAddress}
            setStep={setStep}
          />
        )}
        {step === 3 && (
          <Step3
            orders={orders}
            setOrders={setOrders}
            customerName={customerName}
            customerAddress={customerAddress}
            customerNumber={customerNumber}
            setCustomerName={setCustomerName}
            setCustomerAddress={setCustomerAddress}
            setCustomerNumber={setCustomerNumber}
            setHasOrdered={setHasOrdered}
            setStep={setStep}
          />
        )}
      </section>

      <div className="bottom" ref={bottomRef} />
    </>
  );
}

function OrderInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div className="orderInfo">
      <div className="info__segment" style={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
        <h1>{props.id}</h1>
        <h5>Order ID</h5>
      </div>

      {props.orders.map((o, i) => (
        <div className="keychainInfo">
          <h1>Keychain No. {i + 1}</h1>
          <div className="info__segment">
            <img
              className="keychainImage"
              src={o.keychainImage}
              alt="keychainImage"
            />
            <h5>Keychain Image</h5>
          </div>

          {o.keychainMessage && (
            <div className="info__segment">
              <h3 className="keychainMessage">{o.keychainMessage}</h3>
              <h5>Keychain Message</h5>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className="customerInfo">
        <div className="info__segment">
          <h3 className="customerName">{props.customerName}</h3>
          <h5>Customer Name</h5>
        </div>
        <div className="info__segment">
          <h3 className="customerNumber">{props.customerNumber}</h3>
          <h5>Customer Number</h5>
        </div>
        <div className="info__segment">
          <h3 className="customerAddress">{props.customerAddress}</h3>
          <h5>Customer Address</h5>
        </div>

        <div className="info__segment">
          <h3 className="customerAddress">{props.paymentMethod}</h3>
          <h5>Payment Method</h5>
        </div>
        <div className="info__segment">
          <h3 className="totalPrice">₱ {props.price}</h3>
          <h5>Total Price</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
function OrderManagement() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(
        query(collection(db, "orders"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")),
        (snapshot) => {
          setOrders(snapshot.docs);
        }
      ),

    []
  );

  return (
    <section className="orders">
      <section className="toApprove orders__section">
        <h1 className="segmentTitle">To Approve</h1>
        {orders
          .filter((o) => o.data().status === "toApprove")
          .map((o) => (
            <div className="toApproveOrder Order">
              <OrderInfo
                key={o.id}
                orders={o.data().orders}
                customerName={o.data().customerName}
                customerAddress={o.data().customerAddress}
                customerNumber={o.data().customerNumber}
                price={o.data().price}
                id={o.id}
                paymentMethod={o.data().paymentMethod}
              />
              <div className="toApproveControls controls">
                <button
                  className="declineButton controlButton decline"
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteDoc(doc(db, "orders", o.id));
                  }}
                >
                  Decline
                </button>
                <button
                  className="approveButton controlButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateDoc(doc(db, "orders", o.id), {
                      status: "toCreate",
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  Approve
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </section>
      <section className="toCreate orders__section">
        <h1 className="segmentTitle">To Create</h1>
        {orders
          .filter((o) => o.data().status === "toCreate")
          .map((o) => (
            <div className="Order">
              <OrderInfo
                key={o.id}
                orders={o.data().orders}
                customerName={o.data().customerName}
                customerAddress={o.data().customerAddress}
                customerNumber={o.data().customerNumber}
                price={o.data().price}
                id={o.id}
                paymentMethod={o.data().paymentMethod}
              />
              <div className="controls">
                <button
                  className="controlButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateDoc(doc(db, "orders", o.id), {
                      status: "toShip",
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  Ship Order
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </section>
      <section className="toShip orders__section">
        <h1 className="segmentTitle">To Ship</h1>
        {orders
          .filter((o) => o.data().status === "toShip")
          .map((o) => (
            <div className="Order">
              <OrderInfo
                key={o.id}
                orders={o.data().orders}
                customerName={o.data().customerName}
                customerAddress={o.data().customerAddress}
                customerNumber={o.data().customerNumber}
                price={o.data().price}
                id={o.id}
                paymentMethod={o.data().paymentMethod}
              />
              <div className="controls">
                <button
                  className="controlButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteDoc(doc(db, "orders", o.id));
                  }}
                >
                  Complete Order
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}

function Admin() {
  const securityPassword = "Pogi Ni Vlad";
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return password === securityPassword ? (
    <OrderManagement />
  ) : (
    <section className="login">
      <h1 className="title">Keych Admin Login</h1>
      <div className="login__form">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form__pasword"
          placeholder="Input password to enter: "
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider
      options={{
        "client-id": process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        currency: "PHP",
      }}
    >
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Another evidence]

Comment: Where is the PayPalButtons component? Consider using the sample the package provides as a base https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default

Comment: @PrestonPHX I tried changing the currency to PHP on the sample that you sent me but it's still in USD

Comment: line 10 in that sample

Comment: @PrestonPHX It works now how do i mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `PayPalButtons` component in the first code sample?

Consider using the full [sample the package provides](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) as a base. There's a currency variable set in two locations (line 10 and later within the PayPalScriptProvider) for whatever reason.